# why it is necessary to use semicolon after functions prototype

Tags: c, function, declaration, function-prototypes

Why we use a semicolon after the `int add(int,int)` statement in  second line.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int add(int,int);
int main()
{
int a,b,c;
scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
c=add(a,b);
printf("The sum of the 2 numbers is %d",c);
return 0;
}
int add(int x,int y)
{
int sum;
sum=x+y;
return sum;
}
```

Comment: To distinguish it from the function implementation.

Comment: Because otherwise the compiler would expect you to provide the definition of the function in curly braces (`{ }`)

Comment: Because that's the way the language was specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the C grammar declarations are defined the following way

```
declaration:
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
                                                  ^^^
```

As you can see the semicolon is required.

And this

```
int add(int,int);
```

is a function declaration. Thus you have to place a semicolon at the end of the declaration.

Compare two programs

```
int main( void )
{
    int add( int x, int y )

    {
        //...    
    }
}
```

and

```
int main( void )
{
    int add( int x, int y );

    {
        //...    
    }
}
```

The first program is invalid because the compiler will think that the function `add` is defined within function `main`.

The second program is valid. There is a function declaration and a code block within `main`.

So semicolons are needed that to distiguish declarations from other program constructions.

Answer (score 2):

```
int add(int, int);
```

This is a forward declaration - it's a way of telling the compiler "there's a function called 'add' that takes two ints, so if you see me using it just trust me, I'll define it later". Because you're not defining it yet, you don't need the `{}` curly braces after it. The semicolon appears at the end of every line of code in C, except for after certain braces (e.g. if statements, function **definitions**). So a semicolon is still needed after a forward declaration.

Comment: So, if that is a **forward** declaration, what youd be a **backward** declaration (or any other declaration)? And why does that not need a semicolon?

Comment: @Olaf, There is no backward declaration in C. There's no need to declare the function after you defined it as the compiler already knows it exists. It doesn't need a semicolon because that's the C specification - function definitions, if/else/case statements and preprocessor definitions don't use semicolons for apparently no good reason :) EDIT: C/C++ mixup. Rule still applies

Comment: Wrong language. This is not C++, but C.

Comment: Well, actually a definition is also a declaration. That's why you do not need to declare it lateron. FYI: in addition there are _tentative definitions_, too.

Comment: A declaration after the definition would serve to check they match.  The visibility of various definitions/declaration can be obscured with the myriad of `#include` files.  I have used this in debugging.

Comment: @chux: Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Semicolons end statements in C. So the semicolon tells C that the statement to declare the add function has been terminated, and whatever follows is a new statement.
In this case, this is a function **declaration** and the semicolon states that there is nothing more to be expected. Without the semicolon, a function **definition** would be expected with the curly braces as in `main() {...}`

Comment: Well, at file-level, you do not have any statements, but only declarations and definitions.

Comment: Why was I downvoted? Is this a wrong answer?

Comment: Read my comment. And a definition is also a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Without the semicolon, the compiler is expecting a function definition (starting with an open brace), or a comma to separate the one definition from the next.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon is just a terminating character. As no body to the function is defined (e.g. unlike `main() { ... }` ) it is a way of letting the compiler know not to expect anything else.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand what is declaration and definition in C/C++. When you declare a variable or function, you are telling the compiler there is something with the name whose type is specified. The compiler does not have to get its full definition of the variable or function.

In the example, the function is firstly declared and then defined. The syntax of declaration statement should include a semicolon.

You can get more clear concepts by reading this: http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html

Comment: Just to clarifiy: There is no language C/C++. They are different languages! C++ is **not** "C with classes". (There are just too many people around who think this)

Comment: Yes you are right - C++ involves much more concepts especially after C++ 11/14 but the syntax is similar to C.

Answer (score 0):

The historical reason this was necessary is that, originally, in K&R C, `add()` would have been written:

```
int add()
int x;
int y;
{
  return x+y;
}
```

Without a semicolon after the prototype, it would be hard to impossible to distinguish this from:

```
 int add();
 int x;
 int y;

 {
   /* A nested block. */
 }
```

Remember that the C pre-processor is one-dimensional and turns the program into a list of tokens separated by whitespace.  The parser can’t see newlines or indentation to guess what you meant.

Plus, statements in C generally end in semicolons and it’s easier to be consistent than to make programmers remember a bunch of arbitrary exceptions.